# Find a suitable counterexample?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **Is the following statement true or false?**
>
> If a sequence $(x_n)$ with an infinite range $\{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ has precisely one accumulation point, then $(x_n)$ converges.

I know the statement is FALSE, since there is a theorem that says:

> A sequence $(x_n)$ with an infinite range $\{ x_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ that converges to some limit, has precisely one accumulation point, namely the limit itself.

This is **not** an if and only if statement. However, for the purpose of this question, I would like to give a counterexample, but I cannot for the life of me think of one.

Can anyone please provide me with a suitable counter example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Alternate the terms of a convergent sequence with the terms of a sequence diverging to $\infty$.

Comment: For example $\displaystyle (x_n) = \begin{cases}n & n \text{ odd } \\ 1 - \frac{1}{n} & n \text{ even } \end{cases}$ ??

Comment: @Dillon: Yes, that will work.